# Providing functions versions where both by value and by reference are available

Tags: c++, return, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I defined this function:

```
template <typename T>
void foo (T &result){
  //some very complicate stuff
  result = //something
}
```

Now, let's suppose that sometimes I want to call it with `T=int` and in other cases `T=std::string`. So, in the second case the header is efficient, but with `T=int` [this is inefficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009543/passing-integers-as-constant-references-versus-copying). Notice I'm using only these two types as an example.

So the better solution would be define another function with:

```
template <typename T>
T foo(){
  T result;
  //some very complicate stuff
  return result;
}
```

And let the user decide which version to call, but how do we avoid to call the whole code of `//some very complicate stuff` in the function?

Comment: Operating on integer reference is relatively inefficient but it doesn't cost so much. It's just because copying a integer is also cheap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but with `T=int` this is inefficient

With compiler optimizations enabled that will very likely never matter - the cases where it matter can be detected via profiling and handled separately.

---

> but how do we avoid to call the whole code of `//some very complicate stuff` in the function?

Well, one possible way of avoiding it would require you to pass a *function object* as an extra parameter:

```
template <typename T, typename F>
void foo (T &result, F&& complicated_stuff){
  std::forward<F>(complicated_stuff)();
  result = //something
}
```

```
template <typename T, typename F>
T foo(F&& complicated_stuff){
  T result;
  std::forward<F>(complicated_stuff)();
  return result;
}
```

It is a good solution that will extremely likely be inlined and optimized out by the compiler... but what's the point if all you're trying to do is avoiding to pass a primitive type by reference? We're adding an extra *forwarding reference*  here for the *function object*.

---

Therefore, I strongly advise you to only have a single version of `foo`. The one that returns by value is more idiomatic C++11 and won't be slower than the one that takes a reference due to RVO and *move semantics*.

Comment: Thanks for your useful answer. Just one question: why the move semantics should make the `return` approach not slower than the other one?

Comment: @justHelloWorld: in the best case scenario you get RVO/NRVO, which doesn't even call the move constructor. In the worst case scenario, you get a call to a move constructor, which is negligible in terms of performance for most data structures (as it often consists of 1-2 pointer assignments).

Comment: Thanks for your clarification