# Should the parameters of most/all setter functions in C++ be written as const references?

Tags: c++, setter

Such as

```
    void SetNumbers(const double& a, const double& b)
      {
        m_a = a;
        m_b = b
      }
```

instead of just

```
void SetNumbers(double a, double b) 
  {
        m_a = a;
        m_b = b
  }
```

I've heard it's faster and safer and maybe there's other advantages

Comment: `I've heard it's faster` that is likely true for classes but not necessarily for `int`. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009543/passing-integers-as-constant-references-versus-copying

Comment: Quick answer is: It depends. For simple/easy to copy types it doesn't matter. For complex types where copying is expensive then using references might avoid an extra copy (but on that case you should probably also add an r-value overload)

Comment: @markhc: In most such cases, I'd actually recommend accepting the arguments by value, then assigning with `std::move`. If the arguments are rvalues, they're either constructed directly into the argument space or moved to it, if they're lvalues, they're copied before the call. Either way, if the move assignment overload is `noexcept` (most should be), this means your setter can be `noexcept` too, because all exception triggering code is performed as part of calling it, not within the function itself. Avoids needing separate overloads, and if moving is cheap, costs little, performance-wise.

Comment: More info [Want Speed? Pass by Value.](https://web.archive.org/web/20140113221447/http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/)

Comment: @ShadowRanger I agree with you up until the `noexcept` thing. Doing `void setName(std::string name) noexcept` while technically valid is kind of... bad (for lack of a better word). While the `setName` function will not throw, the call might throw and cause confusion for the user when doing something simple such as `foo.setName("John")`. Then we have more questions like "Look i am only calling this single noexcept function and my code is throwing, wtf C++??"

Comment: @markhc: That's part of learning C++. Giving the `noexcept` guarantee allows additional compiler optimizations, and nothing in the code raises an exception, so it's correct, so omitting it is a needless pessimization. The fact that it's `noexcept` actually helps narrow the cause; raising exceptions in `noexcept` functions triggers specific behaviors (in C++17, it's an immediate `std::terminate`), so if an exception actually gets raised, you know it wasn't caused inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

The two approaches are not equivalent in the case that the copy/move operators of the associated types are non-trivial.

Assuming you don't care about that distinction, (i.e., the effect of the entire function call including any copies/moves is the same in either case), then in general it depends on the mechanical details of the ABI:

- Small types can be passed efficiently, usually in a single register. In this case there is no overhead passing by value since the copy is implicit in the ABI.
- Larger types that cannot be passed in registers must be passed by pointer even when "passed by value", which means that you incur a copy in the pass-by-value case.
- However, if the function is inlined, this copy may disappear since the compiler can see that that the copy is never accessed.
- Passing by value ensures that the arguments can not *alias*, which may help optimize the function more efficiently, and this effect can sometimes be very large (extensions such as `__restrict` can be used to get the same effect for references).
- Inlining can again "negate" the advantage above.

So unfortunately there is no simple answer.

Considering only performance, reasonable heuristic might be:

For types that would be passed in registers on your important platforms, prefer pass-by-value. If you don't know which types will be passed by value, then you could assume that only primitive types are passed by value (but this is usually a pessimistic assumption).

For larger types, where a copy is made (as in your example), for C++11 and later may *still* prefer pass-by-value, since you can `std::move` the argument in the assignment, which for move-capable types will usually be similarly efficient when the function is called with an rvalue. For non-movable types or when the argument isn't an rvalue, both approaches are similarly efficient.

For larger types, where a copy is not made, I recommend passing by `const` reference, except perhaps in rare cases where you can't avoid aliasing problems, in which case a copy is called for.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the parameter type.

If the size of the value is `<= sizeof(void*)`, like an `int` or `float` (and  generally `double`), it's best to pass it by value, that way it'll likely get put in a register, rather than being looked up in memory.

If it's a large object (like an array or a string), if you plan to copy data out of it, it's best as a `const &` (const reference). If you will move or consume the input, it's best to receive it as a `&&` (rvalue reference).