# Why is the copy constructor not called when objects are allocated on heap?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, c++14, copy-constructor

```
class Guitars
{
private:
    int serialNumber{0};
    float price{0.0};
    // GuitarSpecs spec{};

public:
    Guitars(int serNum, float price)
    {
        this->serialNumber = serNum;
        this->price = price;
    };
    Guitars(const Guitars &s)
        : serialNumber{s.serialNumber}, price{s.price}
    {
        std::cout << "Copy" << std::endl;
    };

    Guitars(Guitars &&source) noexcept : serialNumber{source.serialNumber}, price{source.price}
    {
        source.serialNumber = NULL;
        source.price = NULL;
        std::cout << "Move" << std::endl;
    };

    int GetSerial() const { return serialNumber; };
    float GetPrice() const { return price; };
    void SetPrice(float x) { this->price = x; }
};

class Inventory
{
private:
    list<Guitars *> *guitarList;

public:
    Inventory()
    {
        guitarList = new list<Guitars *>;
    }

    void AddGuitar(int serNum, float price)
    {
        Guitars *x = new Guitars(serNum, price);
        // Guitars x(serNum,price);
        guitarList->push_back(x);
    }

    void Display()
    {
        for (auto &&i : *guitarList)
        {
            std::cout << i->GetPrice() << "   " << i->GetSerial() << endl;
        }
    }

    ~Inventory()
    {
        for (auto &&i : *guitarList)
        {
            std::cout << i->GetSerial() << "  "
                      << "deleted " << std::endl;
            delete i;
        }
        std::cout << "List is deleted" << std::endl;
        delete guitarList;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Inventory I;
    I.AddGuitar(12050, 50.23);
    I.AddGuitar(10000, 20.00);
    I.Display();

    return 0;
}
```

Can someone please explain to me why is the copy constructor not called in the code above?

When I created a list of Guitar pointers on the heap along with Guitar object on the heap with a pointer pointing to them and save those pointers in Inventory list, copy constructor is not called. Why is that happening and is this one more efficient since the program is not ganna create copies of object, its created once on the heap and we save the pointer with us.

Comment: pointer on container still seems suspicious...

Comment: Where do you expect copy?

Comment: Where would you *expect* it to be called?

Comment: `std::list<Guitars> guitarList;` or `std::vector<Guitars> guitarList;` seems more appropriate.

Comment: Copying pointers doesn't copy underlying object.

Comment: Because most of the code above uses Guitar pointers not Guitars. Simple thing to do is remove the pointers. You don't need any.

Comment: Frankly `list<Guitars *> *guitarList;` is an abomination, `list<Guitars> guitarList;` is what you should be using.

Comment: What is the best approach for this problem in term of performance?
```list<Guitars *> *guitarList```-----```list<Guitars *> guitarList```---- ```list<Guitars > *guitarList```

Comment: It's generally easier to make correct code fast than make fast code correct.

Comment: None of those at all is best in performance. I'm not sure why you want to use pointers so badly. Use `std::list::emblace_back`, or if you can't for some reason, move operations.

Comment: @MohammadHussein There is no need for pointers at all in the code you've posted.  Let the compiler generated copy constructor and assignment operator do the work, as the compiler knows how to optimize the code in that case.  By using pointers and `new/delete`, what you're doing is taking away the means of the compiler optimizing the code -- thus the code may turn out to run *slower*, not faster.  The "beat the compiler at optimization by using pointers" trick may have worked 20 years ago, but it doesn't always work now in this day and age of optimizing compilers.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie so I should just create my objects on the stack itself , no need for dynamic allocation on the heap?

Comment: @MohammadHussein -- Yes.  All those calls to `new` take time also.  Did you consider that you are calling the allocator every time you do that?  This is in addition to making the program use pointer-aliasing, thus making optimization by the compiler difficult if not impossible to do.  Then add in that `Inventory` as it stands now with the pointers has incorrect copy semantics.  Removing the pointer usage magically gives Inventory correct copy semantics.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Alright , Thank you

Comment: @MohammadHussein - As Paul said, in your code as shown, there is no justification for your code to use dynamic memory allocation.   Although, depending on operations you perform, `std::list` might allocate memory dynamically - but, odds are, the developers of the standard library that works with your compiler will do a better job of that than you have.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie This question was a task in a course I'm taking online, and I was suppose to create the List on the heap and using copy and move constructor to make the program more efficient so instead of copying everytime it adds an object to the list, it should move it.

Comment: *create the List on the heap and using copy and move constructor to make the program more efficient* -- That's bad information.  Creating objects on the heap does *not* increase the performance of a program.

Comment: Can you give us the exact text of that thing about lists on the heap?

Comment: I want to add here that copies *almost* come for free. What really hurts in terms of performance are allocations and cache misses. Also, at least use `std::unique_ptr` instead of raw pointers in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some detailed answer, based on you talking about optimization:

Your have the following code:

```
list<Guitars *> *guitarList;

void AddGuitar(int serNum, float price)
{
    Guitars *x = new Guitars(serNum, price);
    // Guitars x(serNum,price);
    guitarList->push_back(x);
}
```

I think your reason to use all of those pointers is to be faster. If a `Guitars` object would be created on the stack as usual and then be pushed back, that would create a copy, true.
What you could do instead would be to define a move operation for `Guitars` and move the stack object into what you create in the list, like by calling the [move constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor).
But even better would be to use [`std::list::emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/emplace_back), like this:

```
list<Guitars> guitarList;

void AddGuitar(int serNum, float price)
{
    guitarList.emplace_back(serNum, price);
}
```

In any case, if you talk about optimality, those pointers are not good. A pointer requires additional space, and every time the data is accessed, the pointer must be dereferenced. Also, as @PaulMcKenzie wrote in the comments, this can block the compiler from optimizing for you.

Also, making a list member itself a pointer, that is going with `list<Guitars*>* guitarList;` or `list<Guitars>* guitarList;`, is also not a good idea. The only reason I see is if you want to exchange the lists of two `Inventory` objects, but in that case, simply call `std::swap` on the lists.

If you drop the pointers, note how instantly every other code of yours becomes far easier. You don't even have to define your destructor at all.

(As for the actual question you asked, like @Jarod42 already wrote, copying pointers does not copy objects.)

(By the way, if the class `Guitars` represents a single guitar, then I'd go for the singular, `Guitar`.)

Edit:

I created a small series of tests with different ways to fill the list, using `Guitars` mostly unmodified. (I removed the assignments of the non-pointers to `NULL` though.) In any way, I did the following test setup:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

class Guitar
{
private:
    int serialNumber{0};
    float price{0.0};

public:
    Guitar(int serNum, float price)
    {
        std::cout << "Base" << std::endl;
        this->serialNumber = serNum;
        this->price = price;
    }
    Guitar(const Guitar& s)
        : serialNumber{s.serialNumber}, price{s.price}
    {
        std::cout << "Copy" << std::endl;
    }

    Guitar(Guitar&& source) noexcept : serialNumber{source.serialNumber}, price{source.price}
    {
        std::cout << "Move" << std::endl;
    }
};

void test_1()
{        
    std::cout << "test 1" << std::endl;
    std::list<Guitar*> guitarList;
    Guitar* x = new Guitar(1, 2.);
    guitarList.push_back(x);
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void test_2()
{ 
    std::cout << "test 2" << std::endl;
    std::list<Guitar> guitarList;
    Guitar x(1, 2.);
    guitarList.push_back(x);
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void test_3()
{ 
    std::cout << "test 3" << std::endl;
    std::list<Guitar> guitarList;
    guitarList.push_back(Guitar(1, 2.));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void test_4()
{
    std::cout << "test 4" << std::endl;
    std::list<Guitar> guitarList;
    guitarList.emplace_back(1, 2.);
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    test_1();
    test_2();
    test_3();
    test_4();
}
```

The output of this is:

```
test 1
Base

test 2
Base
Copy

test 3
Base
Move

test 4
Base
```

I hope this increases further understanding about how things work here.
The tests can be found under http://www.cpp.sh/35ld6

Also, I wanted to mention, if we talk about optimization, we'd have to talk about *what* we optimize. Right now, we have small lists of objects with almost no content. In that case, one would not optimize at all, as we talk about nanoseconds in difference.
The cases to think about are:

1. A small list of big objects that are easy to move. In that case, we need to make sure that no copy constructor is called, but move would be fine.
2. A small list of big objects that are hard to move. In that case, we only want to use the base operator, possibly by pointers as you initially did - but `emplace_back` also works and makes things easier. Note that the objects being hard to move would hint at a bad design for the class.
3. A big list of small objects. Here we want to use as few constructors as possible, including move constructors. We also don't want to use a list of pointers, as that would give us additional 64 bits per object, and a lot of derefencing later on. In that case, `emplace_back` really shines.

So in other words, you can't go wrong with `emplace_back`.

Comment: Passing `int`s and `float`s by reference is definitely less optimal than passing them by value. Don't do it.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Can you elaborate on that? Right now I only see two copies vs no copies. (Not that I mistrust you, just want to hear the reasons before I edit my answer.)

Comment: If you pass a reference, you are in effect copying a pointer. Since on most 64-bit machines, an `int` and a `float` are only 32 bits, and pointers are 64 bits, you are "copying" twice as much, and you have to pay for the pointer indirection which requires an extra indirect load instruction for every parameter passed by reference.

Comment: @Aziuth Thanks, that helped me a lot :)
Can you add a copy and  move constructor  to the Guitar class above?

Comment: @G.Sliepen I hoped for something like a link, am not entirely persuaded. But I removed that paragraph from my answer. Especially since in any case it is less readable.

Comment: @MohammadHussein On a quick glance, the constructors you have there actually look fine already. Weren't called in `AddGuitar` because you copied a pointer, though.Would be called if you had no pointers and went like `guitarList->push_back(Guitars(serNum, price));`. (But use emplace instead.)

Comment: @MohammadHussein `source.serialNumber = NULL;` is wrong, though. `serialNumber` is not a pointer. You can go with `source.serialNumber = 0;` if you want to. Same goes for the price. Also, you don't need semicolons after the braces of a method definition (only after those of a class definition).

Comment: Here is a link discussing [passing integers as references vs. copying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009543/passing-integers-as-constant-references-versus-copying). Note that compilers are very good at optimizing things, especially if they can do inter-procedural optimization, so if everything is in the same source file, or if link time optimization is used, the compiler will probably optimize away the references. But there are situations where it is not possible to do that, and it is more typing :)

Comment: @G.Sliepen Thank you very much for you effort. Learned something today.

Comment: @MohammadHussein I added some tests on using different approaches.